# How to get current location in background service in android

Tags: java, android, google-location-services

I am using custom GoogleLocationClient for getting the location in the entire project. there is a constructor with two parameters, one is activity and another is Listener, now I want to get the location in background service with using the same class, how to achieve this can any body help me out,

Comment: Please post some code in order to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

*here is a constructor with two parameters, one is activity and another is Listener, now I want to get the location in background service with using the same class*

It actually needs a context not activity exactly.

Anyways, you can follow the google samples of location

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location